# Passing a unique identifier as a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hey, 
I just wanted to know if i have a parameter with a type of uniqueidentifier, how can i pass that in my code as a parameter:

```
personId uniqueidentifier

public IQueryable<Report_person>GetPerson(uniqueidentifier personId)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what your uniqueidentifier is. C# has a `Guid` class that is used for globally unique identifiers, or if this is for a database and you have just an incremental ID number as the identifier and `int` would be fine. Depends on how you are creating the ID and what you are using it for, but usually a unique Identifier in C# is represented by a `Guid` or [Globally Unique Identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx)

```
Guid uniqueId = Guid.NewGuid();

public IQueryable<Report_person>GetPerson(Guid personId) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation i appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 9):

Usually `uniqueidentifier` corresponds with [`System.Guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx), as listed in [SqlDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx).